# Creating a table from a file

Tags: python, list, file, tabular

I have to write a program that creates a partial magic square table.
When running my program the table is printed like this :

```
[int, int, int, int] [int, int, int, int] [int, int, int, int].
```

I would like for it to print my table out as so:

```
[int, int, int, int]
[int, int, int, int]
[int, int, int, int]
```

My question is, how can I go about this when it is reading it from a text file?
my following code attempt is this:

```
text_file = input("Enter the name of the text file: ")
text = open(text_file, "r")
N = int(input("Enter the magic number: "))
print("This is the table")
table = []
nested_list = []
table = text.readlines()


i = 0
for line in table:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split(" ")
    nested_list = []

    for number in line:
        nested_list.append(int(number))

    table[i] = nested_list
    i += 1
for index in range(1):
    print(table)
```

Comment: After this what you get and what you expect? Please provide that

Comment: Please add a new line at the end of each line. its normally \n.

Comment: I put what I get and what I expect at the top before the code but I filled in the data from the table with int instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question but wouldn't this work?

```
for t in table:
    print(t)
```

Comment: he has already done for loop with the table, so probably he knows how to do for loop.

Comment: This answered my question

Comment: Then you may "accept" the answer (up left, close to the vote score).

Comment: I have to wait another four minutes, thank you for the help